# Как изменить свойства одного div-a при наведении на другой с помощью js?

Tags: javascript

Задача:

```css
.one {opacity: 1;}
.two {opacity: 0.3;}
```

```html
<div class="one">content</div>
<div class="one">content</div>
<div class="one">content</div>
<div class="one">content</div>
```

Как сделать с помощью js так, чтобы при наведении на div вместо класса one активировался two на всех div-ах кроме выделенного?

Answer (score 0):

```js
let divs = [...document.getElementsByTagName('div')];

divs.forEach((div, i) => {
  div.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    setClass(i);
  });
});

function setClass(index) {
  divs.forEach((div, i) => {
    div.setAttribute('class', i === index ? 'one' : 'two');
  });
}
```

```css
.one {opacity: 1;}
.two {opacity: 0.3;}
```

```html
<div class="one">content</div>
<div class="one">content</div>
<div class="one">content</div>
<div class="one">content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение с использованием jQuery. На мой взгляд оно лаконичнее.

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.one', (e) => {
    $('.one').removeClass('two').not(e.currentTarget).addClass('two');
});

$(document).on('mouseout', '.one', (e) => {
    $('.two').removeClass('two');
});
```

Вот тут полный код http://jsfiddle.net/12xgfjw5/1/

Comment: Лаконичнее на css это делать, и правильнее ;) а jquery советовать уже точно не правильно. Да и вы класс one забыли удалять

Comment: В принципе уже почти то, что надо, спасибо.
Но как убрать потом выделение, когда мышку полностью убираешь от div-ов, а то активным остается

Comment: А как вернуть все в исходное состояние? Когда мышку убираем, чтобы опять все div-ы вернулись в свой класс .one?

Comment: Добавил в решение код

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev автор спрашивает как сделать на js, если бы спросил ка сделать на css, то другое дело. Предложил решение на jQuery, потому что как правило начинающие кодеры его используют.